# The query with OR statement is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, yii2

this is my query

```
$select = (new yii\db\Query())
                ->select('autori.IDAutore, autori.IParte, autori.IIParte, autori.Prefisso, autori.Qualificazione, count(autori.IDAutore) AS qta')
                ->from('autori')
                ->innerJoin('bibliografie b', '
                b.RIDAutorePrinc1 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAutorePrinc2 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAutorePrinc3 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAutorePrinc4 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAutorePrinc5 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAltroAutore1 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAltroAutore2 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAltroAutore3 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAltroAutore4 = autori.IDAutore OR
                b.RIDAltroAutore5 = autori.IDAutore
            ')->limit(20)->orderby('COUNT(*) DESC');
$autoreList = $select->groupby('autori.IDAutore')->limit(20)->all();
```

The problem is that the loading page is too slow if the result have more than 2000 items. It take 20-30 seconds.
Any suggestion for optimize the query?
Thank you

Comment: That's what you get from a bad database design. I might be old-fashioned, but when I see `RIDAutorePrinc3`, it smells. In my day, when designing databases you would speak of 0, 1 or many, not of 2 or 3 or 4 or 5.

Comment: i think it is better to get all data from both table without join and use backend language to make a joined array against your data it will he better i think

Comment: I haven't design the database, I know that is very bad. Thank you hammad, so if I don't use the join what I have to do?

Comment: Look at other stackoverflow Question with "OR" in the title.

Answer (score 1):

I think based on your query that you should change db design , why you use so many columns ? Maybe i am wrong but you need to optimise this part , `b.RIDAutorePrinc1 , b.RIDAutorePrinc2 ....... b.RIDAutorePrincN` where you can have only one colum `b.RIDAutorePrinc` and put all values in this column and you dont have to put in a join so many `or` conditions .

Firstly join in sql always cost you some time and added here also so many `or` conditions the time goes up . If you put everything in `b.RIDAutorePrinc` you would have a shorter query like below and saving some appreciated time:

```
$select = (new yii\db\Query())
              ->select('autori.IDAutore, autori.IParte, autori.IIParte, autori.Prefisso, autori.Qualificazione, count(autori.IDAutore) AS qta')
              ->from('autori')
              ->innerJoin('bibliografie b', 'b.RIDAutorePrinc = autori.IDAutore')
              ->limit(20)     
              ->orderby('COUNT(*) DESC');

$autoreList = $select->groupby('autori.IDAutore')->limit(20)->all();
```

Comment: Yes if I write the query with only the first author the query is very fast, but I need to have all this foreign key. There are ten colums for ten authors, this is the question. If I write your query the system is fast, but in the result there will only the first author.